# boost::associative_property_map() compile error

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, boost-graph

using this link on boost website, I am able to compile the code [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/property_map/example/example2.cpp). and even get the answer (example). But when I do the same by defining in a class, I get the error as follows:

```
#include < as usual in the code >

class Test{

 std::map<std::string, std::string> name2address;
 boost::const_associative_property_map< std::map<std::string, std::string> >
                  address_map(name2address);


};
```

error is as follows:

```
error: ‘name2address’ is not a type
```

I have to use typedef and typename as follows to compile the code correctly. but I am still unable to use (insert, or the foo function (as provided in example)

please help, here is the code using typedefs

```
class Test{
  typedef typename std::map<std::string, std::string> name2address;
  boost::const_associative_property_map< std::map<std::string, std::string> >
                address_map(name2address);

 };
```

I have to pass this associative property map to another class, where I can use get and put functions as usual. How would i approach that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
boost::const_associative_property_map< std::map<std::string, std::string> > address_map(name2address);
```

declares a variable and initialize it by calling the constructor with name2address. You cannot do it in a class declaration you have to do it in the class ctor :

```
class Test{

 std::map<std::string, std::string> name2address;
 boost::const_associative_property_map< std::map<std::string, std::string> >
                  address_map;
public:
 Test() : address_map(name2address) {}
};
```

This should solve the compilation issue, but I'm not sure it is the best possible layout depending on how you will use Test after that.

Comment: thanks, the thing is, I have declared this in one static class, but I am passing that class to another class as template parameter. and I want to use the map in that new class. the question which was marked duplicate was for this reason.